# Contour Complex integral using Residue

Tags: contour-integration, residue-calculus

I’m trying to calculate

$$ I = \oint \frac{2+ 3\mathrm{sin}(\pi z)}{z(z-1)^2} $$ on a closed contour of radius $3$ centered on $O(0,0)$.

I’ve written this equation substituting $\mathrm{sin}(\pi z)$ by $ \frac{e^{i\pi z} - e^{-i \pi z}}{2i}$.

The equation becomes :

$$ I = 1/2i \oint \frac{4i + 3 e^{i \pi z} -3 e^{-i \pi z} }{z(z-1)^2} $$

Using Residue theorem, I got the sum of the residues $-6i \pi$, dividing by $2i$, it will equal $-3\pi$

Edit:
and multiplying it by $2 \pi i$ of the residue formula I get $I =-6 i \pi ^2$.

The thing is that the professor gave us the answer which is : $ I =-6i\pi$. What’s my fault?
[image: That’s the question]

Comment: Did you remember to multiply the sum of the residues by $2\pi i$? Sounds like you forgot.

Comment: Ohh... looks like i need some rest to refocus again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: By substituting $\sin(\pi z)$ the integration becomes 
$$ I = \frac 1 {2i} \oint \frac{4i + 3 e^{i \pi \color{red}z} -3 e^{-i \pi \color{red}z} }{z(z-1)^2}dz. $$
 The mistake is in red color.

Simply, $$Res(z=0)=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{2+3\sin{\pi z}}{(z-1)^2}=2$$ and 
$$Res(z=1)=\lim_{z\to1}\frac{d}{dz}\Big(\frac{2+3\sin{\pi z}}{z}\Big)=-3\pi-2.$$
Thus $$I=2\pi i (2-3\pi-2)=-6\pi^2 i.$$
So your answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah sure, I corrected it. Thank you

Comment: You got the same answer as mine. I think the mistake is still running somewhere uncaught, since my professor gave us the answer: $$ I= -6 i \pi $$

Comment: I think you should check the problem, is  in the integrals $\sin(\pi z)$ or $\sin( z)$. Otherwise you verify your answer with your professor.

Comment: I will attach the question as an image to the main post.